# React + TypeScriptでのコンポーネントのエラー

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

## React + TypeScriptでのコンポーネントのエラー

### 概要

現在、TypeScript + Reactで開発中ですが、下記の様なエラーが発生いたしました。
エラーの意味と該当箇所は恐らく分かっています。
具体的には、`<Icon />`でundefinedをコンポーネントとして描画しようとしている為なのかなと…。
しかし、それを解決する方法が分かりません。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願いいたします。

### エラー内容

index.js:1 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

### 該当のソースコード

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"

import * as actionTypes from "../utils/actionTypes"

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar'
import SnackbarContent from '@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close'
import CheckCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle'
import WarningIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Warning'
import ErrorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Error'
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info'

interface iVariantIcon {
    [key: string]: any,    // シグネチャー
}

interface iClasses {
    [key: string]: string,
}

const variantIcon: iVariantIcon = {
    success: CheckCircleIcon,
    warning: WarningIcon,
    error: ErrorIcon,
    info: InfoIcon,
}

const Notification: React.FC = () => {
    const classes: iClasses = useStyles()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const closeNotification = () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CLOSE_NOTIFICATION })

    const notificationOpen = useSelector((state: any) => state.NotificationReducer.notificationOpen)
    const variant = useSelector((state: any) => state.NotificationReducer.variant)
    const message = useSelector((state: any) => state.NotificationReducer.message)

    const Icon = variantIcon[variant]

    return (
        <Snackbar
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'center',
            }}
            open={notificationOpen}
            autoHideDuration={2000}
            onClose={closeNotification}
        >
            <SnackbarContent
                className={classes[variant]}
                aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
                message={
                    <Span>
                        <Icon className={classes.icon} />
                        {message}
                    </Span>
                }
                action={[
                    <IconButton
                        key="close"
                        aria-label="Close"
                        color="inherit"
                        onClick={closeNotification}
                    >
                        <StyledCloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                ]}
            />
        </Snackbar>
    )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    success: {
        backgroundColor: '#0074bf',
    },
    error: {
        backgroundColor: '#c93a40',
    },
    info: {
        backgroundColor: '#0074bf',
    },
    warning: {
        backgroundColor: '#c93a40',
    },
    icon: {
        fontSize: 20,
        opacity: 0.9,
        marginRight: 10
    }
}))

const Span = styled.span`
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
`

const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
    font-size: 20;
`

export default Notification
```

Comment: このエラーが発生するとき、 `variant` は何になっていますか？

Comment: console.logで確認しましたが、しっかりsuccessが格納されていました！今のところはsuccess以外は入ってこないです！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reducerのvariantに初期値としてsuccessを格納したところ解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました！